# MySQL query, sum data from table

Tags: mysql, sum

I have two table client and cash.

Table client:

```
ID Name ... other data
------------------------    
1  Bob
2  Marry
3  Tom
```

Table `cash`:

```
ID Cash Id_client_fk
----------------------
1  500  1
2  500  3
3  500  3
4  500  1
```

I want to sum cash from every client, even if not exist in table cash.

The foreign key is `id_client_fk` to table `client -> ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `SUM()` and a left join to achive this:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name, SUM(c.Cash) cash FROM client u
LEFT JOIN cash c ON c.Id_client_fk = u.ID 
GROUP BY u.ID
```

To remove the `NULL` values you could use an `IF` statement:

```
SELECT u.ID, u.Name, SUM(IF(c.Cash > 0, c.Cash, 0)) cash FROM client u
LEFT JOIN cash c ON c.Id_client_fk = u.ID 
GROUP BY u.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite clear it. Please bring examples of data and what result you want. for example, just a few lines to understand the idea.

If I understand correctly, you need something like this:

```
 SELECT client.id,client.name,s.sum_c FROM client INNER JOIN (SELECT `id_client_fk`, sum(`cash_row`) sum_c FROM `cash` GROUP BY  `id_client_fk`) s ON client.id=s.id_client_fk ORDER BY 3 desc limit 20;
```